# jQuery multisortable - how to access the other elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

jsFiddler is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/sCxpu/46/

I am using the multisortable jQuery extension from here: https://github.com/shvetsgroup/jquery.multisortable

What is does is extend the sortable function to allow you to select more than 1 item by holding shift or control.

Once the elements have been moved, the first element i have moved is accessible via:

```
ui.item
```

My question is how am I ment to access the second, third, nth item? I've looked in the debugger and I can't find an array or list of the items I have moved.

The code where i'm looking is in the javascript, line 270.

The only solution i can think of is to do a jQuery select of items with the 'selected' class, but it seems like a code smell, as I think the data should be accessible from either the event or ui variable.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Taking a look to the code it's easy to understand that the selectedClass option is used to access the other elements....

Answer (score 0):

I've spent some time looking through the code that is used and it seems that the collection is not returned. ( Thanks also to gaetanoM  for looking into this for me too)

I've looked into adding the collection in the regroup method.

In this method there is a insertAfter.prevObject which has the collection inside it. However I don't know how this is set and it's also order is inconsistent based on which element you choose to click to drag and potentially is missing the UI.item itself.

I've had to reconsider using the library because of this as I need to reliably know the order of the elements (and on an unrelated note the shift select method selects hidden elements which i need to fix and perhaps fork the code for)